# Returning multiple types and casting

Tags: typescript

A simple Message type:

```
type Message = {
  message: string;
}
```

A function that returns a string or number type based on the argument.

```
function example(arg1: any): string | number {
  if(arg1) {
    return 'hello';
  }

  return 5;
}
```

Now below if I set the return type to `Message`, then I have to **cast** like this: `message: example(true) as string`, otherwise TS will complain. Is there way to get rid of the TS error programmatically (and properly) without casting?

```
function doSomething(): Message {
  return {
    message: example(true) as string;
  }
}
```

Comment: Overloads, perhaps? https://tsplay.dev/ND2v8W

Answer (score 0):

You can't get around casting to a `string` if it's unclear whether your function will return a `string` or a `number`.

The way to avoid this is to either not have a single function return `string | number` or to have `message: string | number`.

You could also include function overloads if you know you will explicitly call it with a literal `true` or `false`.

```
function example(arg: true): string;
function example(arg: false): number;
function example(arg: boolean): string | number;
function example(arg1: any): string | number {
  // ... rest of code
}
```